# Insert Element based on Order from 2 Arrays of Dates

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, sorting

This is my first post and might not be articulating this the best. I would appreciate any help in trying to figure out this problem I am having.

I have 2 Arrays of Dates (Actual Date Objects):

```
const array oldNoteDates = ["June 8, 2022", "June 8, 2022", "July 1, 2022", "July 5, 2022", "July 28, 2022"];

const array newNoteDates = ["July 3, 2022", "July 25, 2022", "July 25, 2022", "July 28, 2022"];
```

I need to insert a new `div` for each `newNoteDates`, but in order with `oldNoteDates`.

So when I start to loop through `newNoteDates`, I need detect where it belongs in `oldNoteDates` and insert a new element.

**Example loop:**
newNoteDates = "July 3, 2022"

It belongs in
oldNoteDates = ["June 8, 2022", "June 8, 2022", "July 1, 2022", **"July 3, 2022"**, "July 5, 2022", "July 28, 2022"]

When loop finds the position, then insert a new div -

```
let newDateDiv = document.createElement('div'); <br>
newDateDiv.innerHTML = Loop Variable that is currently on July 3, 2022; <br>
append to node that has July 1, 2022 Div
```

Comment: I would merge both your arrays into a single one first - and while doing so, instead of the plain date value, insert an object, that has the date as one property, and `isNew` a s a second, that you set to true/false, depending on which array the item came from. Then you sort that one array properly by date, and loop over that. If the `isNew` property of the current item is true - then you know, that you need to insert your new div element at this point.

Comment: Are you saying that there is a one-to-one correspondence between `oldNoteDates` and `div` elements that are already in the HTML document? Can you clarify how those links are established? In fact, it would be helpful if you would create a runnable snippet (using toolbar) that has all set up in HTML and JS code, with your attempt, and where it goes wrong. That way we can answer with that code and the  fix to it.